# grep on xml config file with spaces and equals in server list

Tags: sed, grep, equals, space

I'm in Linux Learning.
I wrote a script that connect to 5 servers (VM) in serverlist file
the config.xml file is in conf directory

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.169.0.4
192.168.0.5
```

the script is :

```
for q in `cat serverlist`
do
echo ============================================================= &>> log.txt
echo $q &>> log.txt
echo ============================================================= &>> log.txt

    ssh $q 'cd /opt/app; find . -maxdepth 5 -type d -name 'conf' -exec bash -c "cd '{}' &&  cat config.xml | grep -n 'app-connector \port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" \address="192.168.0.254"'" \;; exit' &>> log.txt
    
    done
```

In the log file I found :

```
grep: port=: No such file or directory
grep: address=192.168.0.254: No such file or directory
```

after this there is a question which asks to replace 192.168.0.254 with  0.0.0.0 by using sed in the statement:

```
app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="192.168.0.254"
```

for all the serverlist servers.

I'm working since yesterday and anything doesn't work

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you already have an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810065/modify-an-xml-server-on-several-servers

Comment: Thanks I Tried it but after checking log something is wrong on server 192.168.0.5

Comment: Add any issues you are having in the comments to the original solution. Please don't create duplicate logs.

Comment: Okay sorry, will do

Comment: finaly it doesn't work on one server it has changed unexpected statement

Comment: no , so I 'm waiting for the teacher correction